# How do I add my Shipping info to the 'thank you' page in WooCommerce (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a Wordpress site using WooCommerce for online transactions - on the order completed page (the thank you page) I see the Billing Address but not the Shipping Address (even when the addresses are different)

How do I get the Shipping Address to ALWAYS be displayed on this order confirmation page.

Comment: Edit  `order/order-details-customer.php` , scroll to the bottom of the file, you'll notice the Shipping address has been wrapped in a conditional, just comment out the conditional.

Comment: Anand, put this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy file from
`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php`
and put it into
`wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php`.

Take user shipping value from `wp_user_meta` table of wordpress. Its like override template. Add our field to that template.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `order/order-details-customer.php` , scroll to the bottom of the file, you'll notice the Shipping address has been wrapped in a conditional, just comment out the conditional and the shipping address will always be displayed.

You need to do this by [overriding WooCommerce templates](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)